# Yocto build errors: oe_runmake failed

Tags: ubuntu, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe, petalinux

I am trying to build a DPU4.0 image for a SD card which will be used on PYNQ Z2 to run YOLO. When I am trying to use `petalinux-build` , it shows ERROR like this:

```
ERROR: dpu-1.0-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: dpu-1.0-r0 do_compile: ExecutionError('/home/zhaoqi/Desktop/dpu_integration/pynqz2_dpu/build/tmp/work/zynq_generic-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/dpu/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_compile.411180', 1, None, None)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/zhaoqi/Desktop/dpu_integration/pynqz2_dpu/build/tmp/work/zynq_generic-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/dpu/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.411180
```

This is the screenshot of my terminal. [Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCuKl.png)

How can I fix this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include your code and errors as text and not as images (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) ).

Answer (score 0):

1. You have an code error in file named: **dpucore.c**
2. Try to fix that and maybe that's all. If it's a bug in someone else code,
   try to use diffrent commit or tag.